# Delphi Firedac collation issue

Tags: delphi, collation, firedac

I have migrated my application from Delphi xe2 BDE to Delphi 10.1 Firedac.

In one of my form, I retrieve almost 1000 rows and display it in stringgrid.
Using BDE everything is working fine.

When it comes to Firedac component, while retrieving data from database I get following error.

[image]

When i replace FDTable with FDQuery it works fine with order by clause.
Data was entered with different collation and not default 'C' so sorting order differs.

How do I handle it with FDTable only?
Tried using sortoption property but did not succeed

Comment: So because of collation FireDAC fails on a unique index. Is that the problem? If so, fix the collation. If you don't mind and you just want an index for sorting and do not care about used collation, remove unique flag from the index field. There's not much more to advice.

Comment: Even if i fix collation now, data which was entered using other collation previously will still have this problem while viewing

Comment: Well, does your backend contain a unique index field then? I answer for you, no, it cannot, otherwise you were not able to insert same values. In which case you have a wrong setup in your FireDAC table.

Comment: I am having my primary key in place..there is no duplicate data in table.
When I do query with order by it works.

Comment: Yes, and when you do sorting on a different field, it fails on duplicate records exception. Sure, because field for that sorting index is not unique, so just remove unique flag from it. The `Indexes` collection of your table has an entry which mistakenly includes `soUnique` flag in its `Options`.

Comment: Thanks for your information. In our case, 4 columns makes primary key, no unique Id column. When i do .IndexfieldName = column name (type character) then it works..It does not work for all 4 column combo

Comment: Sorry, I can't make much sense of it. It's obvious that the error comes from an attempt to fetch record that violates unique index constraint. From what you say, it sounds that you have set a composite unique index consisting from 4 fields in your table component. And in your backend are stored two records whose values match in those 4 fields (because you have no such index in your backend). And when you try to fetch those records by the table component, you get an exception. Is that the problem?